# Show that measure has a particular property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a general question: If I want to show that my measure has a particular property, how can I do this? For instance, my measure is invariant under orthogonal transformations of my sets, what are my options to show this? Somehow I feel that I don't need to show this for all sets. At least, it should be sufficient to show this for a generating set of my $\sigma $algebra that is invariant under intersections. But I don't see, which theorems tells me that this is okay? Probably, it also makes a difference whether I am investigating $\sigma$- finite measures or general measures.

Comment: You should probably read up on Caratheodory's extension theorem, it might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, this one is for $\sigma-$ finite measures ( therefore question 2: What can I do for other measures?) and it tells me that starting from a generator that is stable under intersections, I find one unique measure everywhere. How do I know that this one unique measure has the property I checked on the generator everywhere?

Comment: Hmm, I think I now understand the question more clearly. Good one!

Answer (score 0):

When the measure is $\sigma$-finite, $E=\cup E_n$, two measures $u,v$ on $E$ are the same iff $u$ coincides with $v$ on $E_n$ and on a $\pi$-system generating the $\sigma$-algebra on $E$.

Comment: this does not answer my question I think, because it does not explain how properties are transfered...

Comment: If you want to show the mesure $\mu$ has property $A$. Then you compare $\mu$ with $\phi$ who has this property $A$. If $\mu=\phi$, $\mu$ has then the property $A$. For exemple, $\phi$ is the mesure obtained by an orthogonal transformation from $\mu$, you need just prove $\mu=\phi$ to show that $\mu$ is invariant under orthogonal transformation.

Comment: okay but coming back to my example, I generally do not know whether a property like invariance under orthogonal transformation is reconcilable with the measure properties. So, what I want to say is: How do I know that there is a second measure that is for example invariant under orthogonal transformations on the whole borel sigma algebra?

Comment: Euh, read the precedent exemple in my comment. The exemple does not correspond very well to what I have said but the same principle applies: to show $\mu$ is invariant under $f$, prove $\mu=f\mu$ where $f\mu$ denote the mesure obtained by composing $f$.